# spring data couchbase N1ql Query parameter

Tags: spring-data-couchbase

I am Using Spring-data-Couchbase 2.1.5. I want to run the following N1QL query on the docs give below. Can anyone suggest how to do it??

**1) N1QL Query**

```
SELECT pkgPrcStsCd, count(*) AS count
FROM `default`
WHERE ANY sort IN busOp SATISFIES sort.opPlnDt = now_str('1111-11-11') END
GROUP BY (pkgPrcStsCd)
```

**2) Docs in the Couchbase is as**

```
{
  "docType": "busOpPrcShu",
  "docId": "busOpPrcShu-US-NJTIN-PKG-1Z2FW2350209207151-171901",
  "docVer": 1,
  "className": "com.operations.package",
  "shuTckNr": "32547354dhfgds",
  "ogzCountryCode": "US",
  "ogzNumber": "12345",
  "pkgXcpRsnCd": "78",
  "pkgPrcStsCd": "01",
  "prcStsUdtTs": "2017-05-19 15:50:30",
  "evtMosRenSleIr": "true",
  "evtTypCd": "02",
  "evtCgyCd": "01",
  "evtTypUdtTs": "2017-05-19T11:45:30Z",
  "eqpNr": "04856374",
  "busOp": [
    {
      "docId": "gkfhgjh",
      "opPlnDt": "2017-05-22",
      "wrkCpt": [
        {
          "docId": "fhkdshfsj"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That query doesn't seem like it can map to an entity type, so this is out of the scope of Spring Data. Spring Data Couchbase would usually apply extra steps when querying for entities, like choosing the concrete class via the `_class` attribute or decoding the document's metadata for the key...

However the `CouchbaseTemplate` has a `findByN1qlFragment` method that doesn't attempt these extra steps but just uses Jackson to unmarshall to the type you provided. So you could have a simple class with 2 fields (one for the `pkgPrcStsCd`, one for the `count`) and use that method.

The query must be built by hand using the Couchbase SDK, either as plain `String` or using the `Select` DSL.

Comment: Thanks Simon... i was able able to get the result using findByN1qlFragment . But Problem i am facing is in parametrized where clause...Can you help me out for below query

Comment: String ramainingPackageByExceptionQuery = "SELECT shuTckNr AS trackingNumber FROM "+"`"+bucketName+"` "+
                "WHERE ANY sort IN busOp SATISFIES sort.opPlnDt = now_str('1111-11-11') END AND evtTypCd = $1";

Comment: JsonArray placeholderValue = JsonArray.from(eventTypeCode);        
        ParameterizedN1qlQuery parameterizedN1qlQuery = N1qlQuery.parameterized(ramainingPackageByExceptionQuery, placeholderValue);        
        List<RemainingPackagesByExceptionData> remainingPackagesByExceptionDatas = couchbaseTemplate.findByN1QLProjection(parameterizedN1qlQuery,RemainingPackagesByExceptionData.class);

Comment: The problem i am facing is log.info("placeholderValue==========="+placeholderValue); is printing "\"03\"" . Ideally it should be "03"

Comment: why use a `JsonArray` if all you need is a plain number? just get rid of the `JsonArray` wrapping 

Comment: Can i pass String without wrapping it into JsonArray or Json Object? I am not able to see anything like

Comment: parameterizedN1qlQuery = N1qlQuery.parameterized(ramainingPackageByExceptionQuery, "03");

Comment: ah my bad, you indeed need the `JsonArray` with the positional parameter... the fact that your log shows the square brackets is just because your printing the array of query positional parameter values, not the array's first value...

Comment: Thanks for your reply Simons...the problem is "\"03\"" . you can see there is "\" . this is due to JsonArray placeholderValue = JsonArray.from(eventTypeCode); where eventTypeCode is string parameter. But when i am doing

Comment: JsonArray placeholderValue = JsonArray.from("03"); here same value is hard coded, then everything works fine.

Comment: what if you log the eventTypeCode variable directly? couldn't it have been already marshalled to JSON or somehow otherwise modified from what you expected it to be?